dotnet missing from runtime dropdown in aws toolkit
I created a project in rider using the LambdaEmptyFunction template. When I try to deploy to AWS using the AWS toolkit I only have node in the runtime dropdown and no option to select dotnet.

Check this: https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-jetbrains/issues/4569
